# What annual payment will discharge a debt of 808 due

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

> What annual payment will discharge a debt of 808 due in 2 years at 2% per annum?

I don't understand what this question means I don't want any solution for this question but can somebody express this in an easy way.

Comment: Well, if  you pay $X$ at the end of the first year, what is that worth in present dollars?  If you pay $X$ again at the end of the second year, what is that worth in present dollars?

Comment: In addition to the on-point questions raised by lulu's comment, it's time to **meta-cheat**.  Where did this question come from?  If from a book or class, what theorems or previously solved problems do you think might be pertinent here?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you know what charging interest means. If, for example, the interest rate is $2\%$ per year ("per annum" in Latin), this means every year the lender counts the debt as if it had increased by $2\%$. For example, if you owe $\$100$ now, in a year you will owe $\$102$ if you don't repay anything in the meantime.

In this case, you owe $\$808$ *now*. You are repaying it yearly ("annual payment"), over two years, and you are repaying the same sum in both years. You want to fully repay ("clear", "discharge") the debt after the second payment. If there was no interest, you would just pay $\$404$ every year. However, the interest is $2\%$, so you will need to pay *more*. **How much**?